# RegexStringValidator not throwing ArgumentException

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, app-config

I have the following code:

```
try
{
    var configSection = config.GetSection("customSectionConfiguration") as CustomSection;
}
catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
    throw new InvalidConfigurationException(ex);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

In my CustomSection class I have a ConfigurationElement which has properties with RegexStringValidator attributes on them like this:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("property", IsRequired=true, DefaultValue="null")]
[RegexStringValidator("^\w*$")]
public string Property {...}
```

Now in my config file I put a value that violates this regex and when I try to load the configuration (`config.GetSection(...)`) an Exception is thrown as expected but it's not an ArgumentException like the RegexStringValidator documentation suggests. Instead it is being caught by the generic Exception with this message: "The value for the property 'property' is not valid. The error is: The value does not conform to the validation regex string '^\w*$'".

Does anyone know what type of exception is actually being thrown or how I can determine this while debugging?

Comment: for a quick and dirty check, you could change your generic catch to `catch(Exception ex)` and put a breakpoint inside the catch block to investigate the type of ex.

Comment: That's what i tried but i don't see anything that lets me know what type of exception it is.

Comment: This time I called ex.GetType() in the watch window and that solved the issue. Turns out it is an ConfigurationErrorsException. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following Paul Griffin's advice it turns out that the type of Exception being thrown here is a ConfigurationErrorsException. I found this out by calling ex.GetType() in the watch window while debugging.